# How do I Exit and Save Access automaticlly using a macro?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am having difficulties developing a macro that saves and closes access automatically after a certain amount of time

I did a bit of research already and tried a couple of vba functions in modules but nothing seems to work

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn what we'll do to help you. TL;DR: this isn't a code writing service so you'll have to provide your best shot at it and indicate where you're stuck, then someone will help you fix that specific issue.

Comment: @Freeman Your TL;DR is longer than the "long" version :D

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook it's shorter than taking the tour and reading the help...

Comment: @Freeman  Fair point.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that easy to get working under all conditions. Thus, a tool has been created by *Peter's Software* to do it for you:

[Inactive Shut Down Control](http://www.peterssoftware.com/isd.htm)

Comment: That's a very old version, I am using Access 2018, this is not compatible

Comment: As it works for Access 2010, convert it to an accdb file.